# javascript variable value into jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a sign up page with inline validation, and having script for email availability in external file but pattern check inside the HTML using jquery but problem is css of elements doesn't change in email check script so i want to pass a variable value from external JavaScript to internal Jquery...
Help me out....

```
// JavaScript Document for live email availability check
function createXMLHttpRequest() {
    var xmlhttp = false;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        try {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } 
        catch (e) {
            try {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } 
            catch (e) {
                xmlhttp = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return xmlhttp;
};

function AjaxFunctionusername(signupemail){alert('call');
    var mygetrequest = new createXMLHttpRequest();
    mygetrequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (mygetrequest.readyState == 4 && mygetrequest.status == 200){
            arrRecevied = mygetrequest.responseText;
            alert(arrRecevied);
            if (arrRecevied > 0) {
            }
            else {
            }
        }
    }

    pars = "";
    pars = "signupemail=" + signupemail;
    domainUrl = "ckh_client.php?" + pars;
alert(domainUrl);
    mygetrequest.open("GET", domainUrl, true);
    mygetrequest.send();
}
```

i want `aarReceived` variable's value to be passed in jQuery as shown below...

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //validation for invalid email ID
        $("#signupemail").keyup(function(){
            var msg = '';
            var emmsg = '';
            msg = document.getElementById('signupemail').value;
            var emailReg = /^[+a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/i;
            if (!emailReg.test(msg)) {
                $(".validation-img-1").css("display", "block");
                $(".validation-img-2").css("display", "none");
            } 
            else if (emailReg.test(msg)) {
                AjaxFunctionusername(msg);
            }
        });
        //validation for invalid email ID ends here
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please take the time to format your code properly. It makes it much easier for both you and others to read.

Comment: jQuery is just a JS library...

Answer (score 0):

Make the following changes-
  
     `function AjaxFunctionusername(signupemail){alert('call');
        var arrRecevied=''; //Note the change. Do not create global vars.
            var mygetrequest = new createXMLHttpRequest();
            mygetrequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (mygetrequest.readyState == 4 && mygetrequest.status == 200){
                    arrRecevied = mygetrequest.responseText;
                    alert(arrRecevied);
                    if (arrRecevied > 0) {
                    }
                    else {
                    }
                }
            }`

```
        pars = "";
        pars = "signupemail=" + signupemail;
        domainUrl = "ckh_client.php?" + pars;
    alert(domainUrl);
        mygetrequest.open("GET", domainUrl, true);
        mygetrequest.send();
        return arrRecevied;
    }
```

In your script,

```
if (!emailReg.test(msg)) {
                $(".validation-img-1").css("display", "block");
                $(".validation-img-2").css("display", "none");
            } 
            else if (emailReg.test(msg)) {
               var value= AjaxFunctionusername(msg);
               //value is your arrRecevied
            }
```

Comment: @Pankaj,mark answer as correct if issue is resolved.

Comment: when i alert the aarReceived variable it shows some value but the value variable alerts to be blank